# Allow my app users to share URLs on their wall - and count the number of shares per user

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, share

I have a FB app written in Drupal + PHP + JS. The user can already connect to my app using the "Drupal For Facebook" module (http://drupal.org/project/fb).

I present several external posts to my app users, each one with it's own URL, with a share/like button next to each which is supposed to allow the user to share *that URL* on his wall.

I have the following requirements:

1. When the user clicks the button, I want a dialog to open allowing him to post the specified URL as a message to his FB wall.
2. When the user posts the URL, I wan't to know it and count it in his user profile.

Questions:

- What is the best way to do it?
- Can it be done with an FB Share / Like / Send button?
- Or do I need to construct my own post and send it on behalf of the user?  In that case which permissions I need for my App?
- How to actually do it ? (A code sample would be great).

Remember that I have to count the actual shares per user

Thanks in Advance,

Ammnon

Answer (score 0):

try the following json codes, seems works for the 4 major social networks http://www.internoetics.com/2012/05/16/count-shares-to-facebook-twitter-linkedin-googleplus/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.